# How to detect if a player is withen 3 blocks of a lava source block (minecraft bukkit plugin)

Tags: plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I was trying to figure out how to create a plugin that acts like frost walker but instead converts lava to magma but I can't seem to figure out how.

Comment: Did you check the decompiled source to see how Frost Walker itself does it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a task which checks the surrounding blocks of a player's location, check the condition for your "lava walker" effect, check if the block surrounding the player is Lava and then simply turning it into Magma. 
Here is some pseudo-code:

*inside repeating task*

```
if player has lava walker:
  for block surrounding player#getLocation:
     if block is lava:
        set block type to magma
```

That should give you a rough idea on how to get started. If you need some more pointers let me know and I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the PlayerMoveEvent and if the player moves, check for all blocks in a radius if that block is lava block.
And if so, you change the Materialtype of the Lavablock to Magma.